# Nodejs, How to delay execution between async iterations that returns Promise

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I have the following function which must return a `Promise` after ALL notifications has been sent successfully/unsuccessfully:

```
sendNotifications : function(notificationArray, successCallback, stats){

        return notificationArray.reduce((acc, x)=>{
                return Promise.all([
                    notificationUtil.sendNotification(x)
                        .then(
                            function() {
                                successCallback(x);
                            }
                        )
                        .catch(e=>{
                            //handle failure...
                        }),
                    new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))//Was thinking it will delay the sendNotification calls but it hasn't.
                ])
            }, Promise.resolve());
    },
```

Here is the `notificationUtil.sendNotification(x)` method:

```
sendEmail: sendNotification (options) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
            someNPM.sendNotification(function(data) {
                if(!data.error_code && !data.is_error)
                    resolve(true);
                else
                {
                    reject(false);
                    console.error("ERROR: " + data.message);
                }
            },
            options);
        });
}
```

The function `someNPM.sendNotification` is from an external NPM, and it doesn't return a Promise, hence, i promisified it.

The problem is that i expected a delay of `1000ms` between `notificationUtil.sendNotification(x)` calls, but its not the case and `sendNotification(x)` is called immediately on all elements from `notificationArray`

Can anyone spot the problem?

EDIT: 
To be clear, my requirement is to wait 1000ms between notifications

Comment: Promise.all starts them *all*, including their 1000ms waits, simultaneously. You're only delaying the finish. If you want delays *between* the actions with all, you'll need to e.g. schedule an increasing wait *before* each one runs. Or use a different construct entirely.

Comment: @jonrsharpe No need to use Promise.all if it doesn't cause the delay to happen in the desired way. Can you please be more specific about the approach you are suggesting?
The requirement is to have a `1000ms` delay between notifications.

Comment: Why are you using `Array.reduce` when you are not using the accumulator?

Comment: @Dijkstra its just a syntax approach. Can easily switch in order to gain the desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible implementation. I didn't check this code but it should give an idea.

```
function timeout(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

sendNotifications : async function (notificationArray, successCallback, stats){
  const length = notificationArray.length;
  const promises = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    promises.push(notificationUtil.sendNotification(notificationArray[i]));
    await timeout(3000);
  }
  await Promise.all(promises);
};
```

Comment: How can you be sure that `sendNotifications ` will return a Promise ONLY AFTER all  `notificationUtil.sendNotification` calls has ended? Please note that `notificationUtil.sendNotification` has an `async` function inside: `someNPM.sendNotification`.

Comment: When you create an `async` function it returns a promise. FUNDAMENTAL!

Comment: One thing you have to do is to await all the promises returned by `notificationUtil.sendNotification`. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: Looks great! Thanks for the help and for explaining!

Comment: @TBE Accepting the answer would be helpful.

Comment: Sure, am testing right now and was planing to accept once confirmed! Thanks.